# swt library - link to eclipse javadoc

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, swt, javadoc

i created a library to ease use of SWT: https://github.com/fab1an/uilib.
I exported javadoc from eclipse which allowed me to specify links to the linked libraries, but for some reason it doesn't work with SWT, the others work fine.

There is the javadoc: http://fab1an.github.com/uilib/javadoc/

This is the ant-script i use for creating it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project default="javadoc">
    <target name="javadoc">
        <javadoc access="public" author="false" classpath="lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar:lib/slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar:lib/jna-3.4.0.jar:lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:lib/gson-2.0.jar:lib/guava-10.0.1.jar:lib/swt-3.7.1-cocoa64.jar" destdir="../uilib-pages/javadoc" doctitle="uilib - (swt) user interface library" nodeprecated="false" nodeprecatedlist="false" noindex="false" nonavbar="false" notree="false" packagenames="org.uilib.templating,org.uilib.measure,org.uilib.templating.components,org.uilib.application,org.uilib.widget,org.uilib.overlay,org.uilib.osdependant,org.uilib.util,org.uilib.registry" source="1.6" sourcepath="src" splitindex="true" use="true" version="true">
            <link href="http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/"/>
            <link href="http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/"/>
            <link href="http://help.eclipse.org/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api"/>
            <link href="http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs"/>
        </javadoc>
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: The URL to SWT javadocs cannot be normally copied, if you try (in broser) go to `http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/overview-summary.html` then it's redirected to some ugly javascript based whatever pages.. I tried to find out, how to avoid this redirect, but with no luck..

Comment: When you disable all JS and go to `http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/index.html?overview-summary.html` you'll get what you want, but how to do it with ant..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it, you have to link to:

http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/

It's possible that the web-server times out, if so you can specify

```
offline=true
```

and

```
packageLoc="./"
```

Then you have to put eclipse's package-list (which you get here: http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/package-list) in your working-directory.